# Filter dataframe in python using pandas based on partial string match

Tags: python, pandas, filter

My Input Dataframe is:

```
list_of_dicts1 = {"Filter":["abc",'def']}

test1 = pd.DataFrame(list_of_dicts1)

list_of_dicts2 = {"C":["a",'z']}

test2 = pd.DataFrame(list_of_dicts2)
```

Output Desired is

```
list_of_dicts3 = {"Filter":['abc']}

test3 = pd.DataFrame(list_of_dicts3)
```

How can I filter dataframe test1 based on "C" column of test2 dataframe using pandas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with `join` by `|` for regex `or`:

```
df = test1[test1['Filter'].str.contains('|'.join(test2['C']))]
print (df)
  Filter
0    abc
```